# how do i read a binary .Chn format file in java?

Tags: java, file, binary, format, byte

a binary file in .chn format was created by a company. he has share a guide to read it. the image below explains how to read it. i have tried with java and so far i cannot succeed. Please someone could help me.
thank you in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8T6V.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAkvW.png)

Comment: *"i have tried with java and so far i cannot succeed."* - Please share your attempt with us.  This is not a place to ask people to write code for you, so we need to see what you have written in order to help you.

Comment: For instance use a ByteBuffer and you can do `readShort` etcetera. An initial `byteOrder` is needed for little endian byte order.

Answer (score 0):

I use *RandomAccessFile* then *readInt ()*.
the file was read, but I noticed when the value of readInt ()> 256 the program gives me an incorrect value.